# how to display selected value from radiobuttonlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I tried

```
Dim theme = rblTheme.Items(rblTheme.SelectedIndex).Value
```

getting first value selected

```
Dim theme = rblTheme.SelectedItem.Value
```

getting first value selected

```
Dim theme = ""
        For i As Integer = 0 To rblTheme.Items.Count - 1

            If (rblTheme.Items(i).Selected) Then
                theme = rblTheme.Items(i).Value
            End If
        Next
```

Getting both value selected.

Need help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim selectedItemVal as string
 selectedItemVal=rblTheme.SelectedValue;
```

I  guess you are reloading the RadioButton list in the page postback again (when you click on some button). So probably you should move that code If isPostBack property is false

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
        //Your code to load the Radio button list control
     }
 }
```

Now you should be able to get the value on your button click event.

Comment: @coders_zone :Check my updated answer. Use Visual studio breakpoints to see the content of dropdown while debugging

Comment: yes, i put it inside the `if` condition and now it works !! thanks !!